# angularjs not returning php data, tried everything

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am learning Angularjs and i am stuck with getting data from PHP file.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("new",[]);
    app.controller("control",function($scope,$http){
      $http.get("index.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.database = response.data;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="new">
  <div ng-controller="control">
    <h1>{{database}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

This the angular script i wrote. My php code is very simple

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  echo "How are you?";
?>
```

I am not able to get php data onto my html file using angularJS. 
I checked the code twice and nothing seem to be missing. I even tried `json_encode()`. Did i miss something?

Comment: check your network tab (console tab where you check js errors), is the call actually triggers

Comment: have you checked the response status? maybe the file request fails in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before all check you php file in right palace using console

In you php code

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  echo json_encode("How are you?");
  exit();
?>
```

And in you controller

```
$http.get("call.php").then(function(response) {
    $scope.database = response.data;
  });
```